# How to import firestore's RPC api/definitions in a .proto file?

Tags: scala, sbt, google-cloud-firestore, scalapb, akka-grpc

Wrt a scala application for interacting with firestore's RPC apis, and using scalapb proto compiler /akka-grpc middleware, how to import the firestore RPC API's definitions in the .proto files? Eg. how to import the [Document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rpc/google.firestore.v1beta1#google.firestore.v1beta1.Document) definition?

Trying to plainly say `import "google.firestore.v1beta1.Document";` gives error.

Answer (score 1):

> take a look at
>   https://github.com/thesamet/sbt-protoc/blob/master/examples/multi-with-external-jar/build.sbt
>   You need to add `libraryDependencies += "com.google.api.grpc" %
>   "proto-google-cloud-firestore-v1beta1" % "0.37.0" % "protobuf"`, which
>   will make `sbt-protoc` extract the protos into a subdirectory of
>   `target/protobuf_external` If you want ScalaPB to generate Scala classes
>   for them, then also add `PB.protoSources in Compile += target.value /
>   "protobuf_external" / "com" / "google"`